# Как получить дату из DateRangePicker в миллисекундах?

Tags: android

Как мне получить дату (дату начала и конца) в миллисекундах из `DateRangePicker`.

По стандарту, используя метод `.getHeaderText`, он возвращает дату в виде `23 фев. - 8 мар`.

Comment: Форкнуть либу и допилить. Либо спросите у автора либы где он этот метод задел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете конвертировать строку с датой в объект Date.

```
String dtStart = "23 фев 2020";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    long millis = date.getTime();  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Обратно в строку конвертируется подобным способом.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");  
try {  
    Date date = new Date();  
    String dateTime = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + dateTime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Вот здесь, вам скорее всего придется поиграться с паттерном, потому как я точно не помню как верно его писать. Необходимо потестить и подебажить.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY")
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat 
Здесь вы можете почитать про паттерны даты и как их писать.

Answer (score 1):

Получить `timeStamp` можно используя `Calendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

все остальное вы получаете уже из `DateRangePicker`